# jQuery's appendTo method causes "context is undefined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A page has two drop-downs which should be populated from a JSON array. When the array is processed it contains the *option* elements which need to be appended to the drop-downs. This task is granted to the jQuery's [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) method which, however, causes an error to appear:

> "TypeError: context is undefined".

Do you know why this is happening and how to fix it?

The source code is available below, as well on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cq5507et/).

HTML:

```
<select id="ddlTypeNew">
    <option value="">Select Type To Add</option>
</select>
<select id="ddlTypeEdit">
    <option value="">Select Type To Edit</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
var json = $.parseJSON('[{ "MailTypeId": 1, "MailTypeName": "Register" }, { "MailTypeId": 2, "MailTypeName": "Login" }]');

json = json.map(function (obj) {
    return $('<option>', { value: obj.MailTypeId, text: obj.MailTypeName });
});

$(json).slice().appendTo('#ddlTypeEdit');
$(json).appendTo($('#ddlTypeNew'));
```

Comment: `var json = json.map...`?

Comment: Yes, this is a silly omission, but even after that the same error appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map` here actually returns a array of jQuery `option` objects. You need to loop through the array and then add them one by one to the dropdown like this:

```
var json = $.parseJSON('[{ "MailTypeId": 1, "MailTypeName": "Register" }, { "MailTypeId": 2, "MailTypeName": "Login" }]');

var arr = json.map(function (obj) {
    return $('<option>', { value: obj.MailTypeId, text: obj.MailTypeName });
});

$.each(arr, function(i, n){
   n.appendTo('#ddlTypeEdit');
})
```

OR JUST:-

```
$('#ddlTypeEdit').append(arr);
```

Comment: Just for information - is there a more direct way to populate the dropdowns without using the each loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
    var json = $.parseJSON('[{ "MailTypeId": 1, "MailTypeName": "Register" }, { "MailTypeId": 2, "MailTypeName": "Login" }]');

    $.each(json,function (index,obj) {
       $($('<option/>').val(obj["MailTypeId"]).html(obj["MailTypeName"])).appendTo('#ddlTypeEdit');
       $($('<option/>').val(obj["MailTypeId"]).html(obj["MailTypeName"])).appendTo('#ddlTypeNew');
    });
```

Comment: Actually, this works. But only the second dropdown is populated:) This is why I used the slice method.

Comment: The fixed typo does not populate the first dropdown. Try with the slice method from my source above.

Comment: @DimitarAngelov, thanks for this question, i got to know to something new, and no need of slice (now the above code works fine), whenever we add an object to the DOM element it cannot be added again. Either we have to re-create the object or store it in multiple variables.